# How to write a script to mimic mpic++ for MPICH2 with MinGW/MSYS

Tags: bash, gcc, mpi

I've installed MPICH2 windows binary from  [their download page](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpich2staging/goodell/downloads/index.php?s=downloads) ([x86_64] 1.4.1p1). I can compile programs and run test code using bare `gcc` as follows

```
g++ -I... test.c -lmpi -L...
```

(with TDM-gcc4.8.1 64-bit plus MSYS). I could also use `mpiexec` to run the compiled binary correctly.

But I couldn't find `mpicc` or `mpic++` in the MPICH2 installation folder.

I was wondering if it is possible (and how) to write wrapper scripts (e.g. bash) around `gcc` for `mpicc` and `mpic++` such that they behave the same way `mpicc` and `mpic++` do under linux.

Thanks

Comment: MPICH probably doesn't work on Windows anymore. It hasn't been tested in quite some. Time. You might check out MS-MPI (free) or Intel-MPI (paid) instead.

Comment: @WesleyBland The old MPICH2 binary still works. It just lacks the `mpicc` and `mpic++` wrapper. I cannot use MS-MPI because I want to keep using GCC as I do in Linux. I am just trying to make what works on Linux work in windows with an old version of MPICH2. I am testing the code on windows and will actually use it in a Linux cluster.

Comment: Also, there are old open-mpi binaries (1.6.2 and earlier) that still work. But they seem to be based on visual c++ only.

Comment: Ah. Well in that case you could at least roll your own compiler wrappers. It's a bit of a pain, but you only do it once. I still have no idea where the wrappers would be.

Comment: I get the feeling from reading the [README.txt](http://www.mpich.org/static/downloads/1.4.1p1/mpich2-1.4.1p1-README.txt) that they do not provide wrappers for Windows and rather expect you to manually add `mpi.lib` and the path to the include files to your project (also they expect you to use Visual Studio).